# Where should I store an object? - QuadTree

Tags: quadtree, space-partitioning

I'm designing a QuadTree to scene partitioning, I've read theory and seen some code examples.

When a node has more than 4 objects, it will be splitted into 4 sub-nodes and its objects will be put into them, but if an object is on the edges of any sub-node, it will be placed in the parent node. **Why should I do this?**

I think it's better put it on every sub-node where it's colliding. **Am I wrong?**. I've designed a pattern to achieve this ;).

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions to this problem. You can place the object in the smallest node which fully contains it. You can split its edges among multiple nodes and tag them with which object they belong to. Another solution is to use a "loose" quadtree. The idea with a loose quadtree is that the nodes are larger than in a normal quadtree, such that they overlap. This means that you can hold larger objects further down the tree. Usually you choose which node to place an object in with a loose quadtree according to the coordinates of its origin.

Answer (score 1):

One chief concern of putting the object in *every* leaf node it occupies instead of the inner node that actually contains it is that, when traversing the tree, you have to track whether you have visited that object before or not. Consider the following case:

A large box spans four leaf nodes, and you are testing if a smaller sphere that straddles two leaf nodes intersects it. Unless you keep track of all the objects you have already collided with you will end up colliding the sphere against the box twice. If, instead, the large box is in the parent node that fully encloses it, you only collide with it once on the way done the tree.

If you have an efficient way of managing this (and there are some) then it is not as important to worry about whether you chose an object in leaf nodes, or object in inner node approach.